# How to add reply(child comments) to comments on feed in getstream.io python

Tags: python, getstream-io

I am using getstream.io to create feeds. The user can follow feeds and add reaction like and comments. If a user adds a comment on feed and another wants to reply on the comment then how I can achieve this and also retrieve all reply on the comment.

Answer (score 1):

getstream.io supports child reaction to reactions. The documentation is [here](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#reactions_add-child).

When you add a reaction to an activity, use the reaction to create child reaction.

```
comment = client.reactions.add(
            "comment",
            activity_id,
            user_id="mike",
            data={"text": "@thierry great post!"},
            target_feeds=["notification:thierry"],
)
```

For example, create a child reaction 'like' to the above `comment` reaction.

```
client.reactions.add_child("like", comment, user_id="thierry")
```

Similarly, create a child reaction 'comment'

```
client.reactions.add_child(
          "comment", 
           comment, 
           user_id="thierry", 
           data={"text":"Thanks @mike"},
           target_feeds=["notification:mike"],
)
```

Retrieve the child reaction of an reaction

```
# retrieve first 10 likes for an reaction
response = client.reactions.filter(
    reaction_id="ed2837a6-0a3b-4679-adc1-778a1704852d", kind="like", limit=10
)
```

Retrieve the parent reaction of an activity

```
# retrieve first 10 likes for an activity
response = client.reactions.filter(
    activity_id="ed2837a6-0a3b-4679-adc1-778a1704852d", kind="like", limit=10
)
```

Note: Child reaction cannot have child reactions. To know more about the paginating & retrieving, read the documentation [here](https://getstream.io/docs/python/#reactions_retrieve-reactions).

Comment: This filter is not working with kind when I am doing filtering with this function it is also giving comment data in the output

Comment: Can you share your code? Also, have you checked the documentation link? These are examples from documentation itself.

Comment: @Madhavikumari what 's the error when you try to use the filter?

Comment: @Madhavikumari stream fixed the issue with reaction filter in their latest python client. use 3.1.0 https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python

Comment: They now support 3 levels of nesting - so now you can like replies to comments https://getstream.io/docs/reactions_add_child/?language=js

Answer (score 0):

you can add the child reaction by using reaction_id